# Does has_one through not provide a `create_child` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image_assignment, as: :imageable
  has_one :image, through: :image_assignment
end

class ImageAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

u = User.new
u.create_image #=> undefined method `create_image'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's correct. you need to build/create the image_assignment first

```
u.create_image_assignment
u.image_assignment.create_image
```

Comment: Ah, ok that's what I ended up going with. Thank you!